# How to read the password from the text file in perl

Tags: linux, perl, sftp, perl-module, password-protection

I am new to perl script, The below code is downloading the files from sftp server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    'auser@sftp.rent.com',
    password => 'auser123',
    more     => ['-v']
);

$sftp->get('outgoing/DATA.ZIP', '/home/sar/')
  or die "unable to retrieve copy: ".$sftp->error;

$sftp->disconnect;
```

Here i have hard codded the password, I want to avoid password in the script, Is there any other method to read the password from the file or any method is there?

I searched in the stackoverflow and google, i don't know how to use this. I tried below one.

```
PASSWORD=`cat /home/sar/passwd_file.txt`

my $password = $ENV{'PASSWORD'}
```

Could you please help me to resolve this code.

Comment: When you are using SSH FTP, do you really want to ruin that security by storing your password in plain text? I see there is an option `key_path` where you can store a file name for your authentication key.

Comment: i am new to perl, I don't want to hard code the password in the script, i thought read the password from file and to give the read permission only to particular user. what are the ways to achieve this

Comment: Google "ssh generate key". What you do is basically set up a pair of keys for the server you want to log in to, then login is automagic.

Comment: I don't want do it through ssh generate key. any other way

Comment: Why not? That is the usual way to automate login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store password in file with limited permissions, but using ssh keys is still better solution.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    'auser@sftp.rent.com',
    password => get_passw("chmod_600_passw_file"),
    more     => ['-v']
);
```

---

```
sub get_passw {
  my ($file) = @_;
  open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

  my $pass = <$fh>; # do { local $/; <$fh> };
  chomp($pass);

  return $pass;
}
```

If you want to store both user/pass in file separated with `:` you can,

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    get_credentials("chmod_600_passw_file"),
    more     => ['-v']
);
```

---

```
sub get_credentials {
  my ($file) = @_;
  open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

  my $line = <$fh>;
  chomp($line);
  my ($user, $pass) = split /:/, $line;

  return ($user, password => $pass);
}
```

Comment: No need to do the `$/` thing for a one line password. If you have more than one line, the password won't work anyway.

Comment: @TLP you're right, but ikegami somewhere wrote that `$str = <$fh>` is bad idea so I avoid that since.

Comment: I doubt he meant it that way. That would invalidate most of Perl's file IO.

Comment: @TLP it was about reading three lines from file and `while` with `last` if count=3 was suggested.

Comment: I have not seen that.

Comment: If i want to use username/password to read from the file then how can i use

Comment: if i use 
$user= get_credentials("chmod_600_passw_file");
$password= get_credentials("chmod_600_passw_file");

i am getting password only, username is not getting here

Comment: @user2767714 try `my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    get_credentials("chmod_600_passw_file"),
    more     => ['-v']
);`

Comment: How to mention the server name here! "sftp.rent.com", 

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host=>$server,user=>$user,password=>$password) or die "unable to connect";

Comment: @user2767714 `auser@sftp.rent.com:auser123` is user@host:password in secret file

Answer (score 0):

To do it exactly like you outlined, first create a shell script in which you run that PASSWORD environmental variable setting command and then launch the perl script you are writting. Of course, incorporate the second (perl) line that you found into your script.

It won't be much safer though, you should consider using other forms of authentication.

Comment: Any steps do you have?

Comment: Passing passwords in environment variables is quite insecure as anybody logged into the machine would be able to see them (run `ps ae` and see)